# Converting string to sortable number

Tags: c#, sorting

Is there any way of converting a string value (any content) to a number such that they both sort in the same way? I don't need to be able to convert the number back to a string. In fact it would be an advantage if it were impossible to convert it back.

I don't need to be able to sort any length of string. If a 64-bit long integer is used as the sort-value then I could trim the texts to a value that fits this number range.

Comment: It is not really possible without you setting certain hard restrictions on what those strings could be and then create a string->long converter which for any string obeying those restrictions would produce a unique long. Without you being able to define such restrictions, a string-to-long conversion will not provide unique long values for any string. Why not? Because a long is just 8-byte (64-bit) data - which could be uniquely mapped to approximately any ASCII/ANSI string with up to 8 or 9 characters only (ignoring non-printable characters ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there can be 100% correct way since sorting a string depends on the culture. For ex

```
int c1 = String.Compare("AA", "BB", false, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")); //return -1
int c2 = String.Compare("AA", "BB", false, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")); //return  1
```

The closest thing I can think of is:

```
ulong l = BitConverter.ToUInt64(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str), 0);
```

PS: pad *str* if its len is shorter than 8

Comment: To match ordinal sorting of the strings you would have to use an unsigned long instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the first 8 bytes from the string, the 8 bytes would make up a ulong. It would only be 4 characters of the string with unicode, or 8 characters if you limit the strings to ASCII.